# Override glyphicons to use the old fashion background property

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a way to override the Bootstrap's glyphicon styles and use the traditional CSS background property without breaking existing markup (for example `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>`)

Here is my attempt but it's still not working:

```
.glyphicon-comment:before {
    content: none;
}

.glyphicon-comment {
    background: transparent url('someurl') no-repeat 0 -380px;
}
```

**Edit**:

Solved by specifying hegth and width to the glyphicon class as shown below:

```
.glyphicon {
    width:14px;height:14px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on http://getbootstrap.com :

```
.glyphicon.glyphicon-comment:before {
    content: none;
}
```

If you don't want to preserve the icons's space, you could also try

```
.glyphicon.glyphicon-comment {
    display: none
}
```